# 3NF Database normalization (Erwin)

Tags: sql, erwin

I have a table and I'm trying to split it in a few more tables to get a 3nf, can someone help me? When I validate my tables with Erwin Data Model Validator I get no warnings...but it's not a 3nf(

http://i43.tinypic.com/35mmuwx.png

and my Erwin scheme:
http://i42.tinypic.com/2hnvx3o.png

Will appreciate any help )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that on Title and on Manager, you should NOT have employee_ID. You shuold have job_Id and mng_id on your Employee table, so the manager and the Title exists only once on your tables and just reference them from your employee table by their Id.
job_start_date and job_end_date should be in your Employee table, unless there is a real reason to use a separate table (like storing multiple start / end dates, but it doesn't seem the case). The same happens with the salary, although I don't know about min and max salaries. If that data is inherent to the job title, then those two fields should be in the Title table.

Comment: Ok, now it looks a bit better ) but still not sure  http://i39.tinypic.com/dz8axd.jpg

Comment: @Caerus haha still a little extra to go: you still need your Employee PK to be Employee_Id, so on Employee your mng_id and job_id should be regular fields (they are still FK, just not a part of your PK), and you also removed the manager_name from manager and shouldn't have